# Preinstalled python on mac a cpython?

Tags: python, macos, cpython

As the title says,I want to know if the python which comes pre installed on mac is cpython. I mean logic says it probably is,but I couldn't find it being written anywhere officially so wanted to confirm.
 I want to download a few things and for compatibility they require the installed python to be cpython/iron python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With command `Python --version` you get the information like that:

> [GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5367)] on darwin

It is almost affirmative that it is `cpython` with `gcc` as compiler.

An alternative(which is more **official**) is to check with python code:

```
import platform
platform.python_implementation()
```

The function [python_implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.python_implementation):

> Returns a string identifying the Python implementation. Possible
>   return values are: ‘CPython’, ‘IronPython’, ‘Jython’, ‘PyPy’

Comment: awesome! python_implementation() returned cpython. thanks a lot! :D